# asp.net MVC custom Authorize attribute, passing parameters and method details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, custom-attributes

I am trying to create a  MVC Custom Authentication Attribute.

I have this method as follows:

```
[DealerContextRequired]
[CustomerContextRequiredAttribute("Invoice", "InvoiceNumber", invoiceNumber)]
public ActionResult InvoiceModal(string invoiceNumber)
{
    if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
       return RedirectToAction("InvoiceModal", "Orders", new { area = "my_account", headerNumber = invoiceNumber });

    InvoiceHeader invoice = _invoiceReader.Get(invoiceNumber, false);

    if (_dealerContext.CurrentFranchisee != null)
    {
       var order = _orderReader.GetByInvoiceNumber(invoice.InvoiceNumber).FirstOrDefault();
       if (order == null)
             return HttpNotFound();

       if (order.Franchisee == null || _dealerContext.CurrentFranchisee.Key != order.Franchisee.Key)
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }

    return PartialView("InvoiceModal", invoice);
}
```

Below is the attribute I have created so far, I am struggling to pass the values form the controller attribute to the attribute, please see the attribute class below:

```
public class CustomerContextRequiredAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public object Entity { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
    public CustomerContextRequiredAttribute(object entity, string key, int value)
    {
        this.Entity = entity;
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var customerContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<CustomerContext>();
        var _customerReader = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ICustomerReader>();

        var entity = this.Entity;
        var key = this.Key;
        var value = this.Value;

        // some logic required for the attribute I am creating based on the above three values..

    }
}
```

**This will be required on multiple actions so how do I get the required data / fields on the custom attribute?**

Comment: Attribute parameters value in controller is not available in `OnAuthorization` method in `CustomerContextRequiredAttribute` class?

Comment: IMHO, I'm not sure this _should_ be implemented as an "Authorization Filter". It _seems_ you just want to ensure that `Invoice` exists, rather than checking if the request is authorized (who not what)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it should work. Passing the values to the constructor like this is acceptable.

You could try removing them from the constructor and doing the following:

```
[CustomerContextRequiredAttribute(Entity = "Invoice", Key = "InvoiceNumber", Value = invoiceNumber)]
public ActionResult InvoiceModal(string invoiceNumber)
```